# Server install hdfs client fail

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am getting the following errors for HDFS client installation on Ambari. Have reset the server several times but still cannot get it resolved. Any idea how to fix that?

stderr:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/hdfs_client.py", line 120, in <module>
    HdfsClient().execute()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 219, in execute
    method(env)
 File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/hdfs_client.py", line 36, in install
    self.configure(env)
 File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/hdfs_client.py", line 41, in configure
    hdfs()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons/os_family_impl.py", line 89, in thunk
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/hdfs.py", line 61, in hdfs
    group=params.user_group
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.env.run()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 152, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 118, in run_action
    provider_action()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/providers/xml_config.py", line 67, in action_create
    encoding = self.resource.encoding
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.env.run()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 152, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 118, in run_action
    provider_action()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 87, in action_create
    raise Fail("Applying %s failed, parent directory %s doesn't exist" % (self.resource, dirname))
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Applying File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/hadoop-policy.xml'] failed, parent directory /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf doesn't exist
```

Comment: You should used HDP 2.3.2 and Ambari 2.1

Comment: @adouang, the version of ambari server is 2.1.2 and the hdp stack is 2.3

Answer (score 1):

This is a soft link that link to **/etc/hadoop/conf**

I run

```
python /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/HostCleanup.py --silent --skip=users
```

After run it, it removes `/etc/hadoop/conf`

However, reinstall does not recreate it.

So you may have to create all conf files by yourself.
Hope someone can patch it.

Answer (score 1):

```
yum -y erase hdp-select
```

If you have done installation multiple times, some packages might not be cleaned.

To remove all HDP packages and start with fresh installation, erase hdp-select.

If this is not helping, remove all the versions from `/usr/hdp` delete this directory if it contains multiple versions of `hdp`

Remove all the installed packages like `hadoop,hdfs,zookeeper etc.`

```
yum remove zookeeper* hadoop* hdp* zookeeper*
```

Comment: Just `yum -y erase hdp-select` worked for me to fix the failing node.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem: I was using HDP 2.3.2 on Centos 7.

**The first problem:** 
Some conf files point to the /etc//conf directory  (same as they are supposed to)
However, /etc//conf points back to the other conf directory which leads to an endless loop.

I was able to fix this problem by removing the /etc//conf symbolic links and creating directories

**The second problem**
If you run the python scripts to clean up the installation and start over however, several directories do not get recreated, such as the hadoop-client directory. This leads to exact your error message. Also this cleanup script does not work out well as it does not clean several users and directories. You have to userdel and groupdel.

UPDATE:
It seems it was a problem of HDP 2.3.2. In HDP 2.3.4, I did not run into that problem any more.

Answer (score -1):

Creating `/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf` on failing host should solve the problem.

Comment: This will actually not create a mess and might not even work out. All configuration is supposed to be in a subfolder under /etc. So deleting /etc/hadoop/conf (which is a symbolic link linking back to /user/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf) and recreating the conf dir is an alternative workaround (although still dirty)

Comment: this did NOT work for me, I ended up starting from a fresh OS install